# Insert date into a range

Tags: vba, excel

I would need a code to allow me produce the specific date to a range of rows in a column. So far, I only know how to do it using Excel function but I have more than 500 rows thus it would be time consuming to manually make changes.

I would like to insert "4/9/2015" on the date column in column A. The current Excel function that I have done is `=Today()`.

Is there any Excel VBA I could use to insert specific dates in a range of rows?

Comment: You can select 500 cells, enter "4/9/2015" and confirm with `Ctrl`+`Enter`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure, if that's what you need ?

```
Sub test()
For i = 1 To 500
    Cells(i, 1) = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know of any code that would allow me to find the day difference between 2 dates?

Comment: DIFF = DateDiff("D", "15/11/2013", "22/11/2013")

Answer (score 2):

you will find this information at MSDN too.

```
=date 'date
=now 'date + time
```

---

```
For each cell in range(insert range here)
    cell = yourDate
next
```

Comment: As in VBA coding is there any code that i could do?

Comment: I havent tried any yet. Because i am still doing research

Comment: OP is requesting to put in a specific date, not the date of today ;)

Comment: That was just for an example. :)

Answer (score 0):

@nabilah In Excel, make your developer tab display on your ribbon. Then record the action you want to do. Then view and edit your code. It won't do everything but it is a good place to start your VBA quest.